# how to change the names of these nodes given below in firebase. this firebase is connected to android studio app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTcvv.png)

these marked numbers are random generated by code from android studio on firebase I want to know about the function so that it can update the number to some name i-e node 1 and node 2 and furthermore if we add some other node it will display node 3 and so on.

Comment: If you're asking how to [rename an existing node in Firebase Realtime Database](https://www.google.com/search?q=rename+an+existing+node+in+Firebase+Realtime+Database), that isn't possible. See the linked search results for details. --- 

If you're asking how to not write those numbers to begin with, we will have to see your current code to be able to say how you need t modify it. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there makes it much more likely that we can help.

Comment: Are you looking to rename an existing node in Firebase Realtime Database? Please respond using @AlexMamo